# Azure Machine Learning : unable to create compute instance with 12 month trial license

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am preparing for DP-100 certification.
As a part of self-learning, I created one trial account using my outlook email for 12 months.
During the part where I needed to set up a **Compute Instance**, I encounter an error as shown below.
What is the reason, Can't I create a **Compute Instance** with a trial account.

[image]